# How to check if Hashmap is not null or empty in JSP using struts 2 tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, hashmap

I want to check if `HashMap` is not empty in JSP using Struts 2 tag. I am using below code.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

```xml
<s:if test="#map != null">

</s:if>
```

Please suggest the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure it's not null server-side, for example by instantiating it while declaring it:

```
private Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

`null` is a meaningless concept, so avoid it in your webapp as much as you can.

Then use `isEmpty()` :

```xml
<s:if test="map.empty">
```